# Add information to DB from the controller on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add the user id to 2 columns in the db after a user successfully submits a form. The commands run fine in the console but wont work in the controller. I haven't added info to the db straight from the controller before so I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the create method

```
 def create
   @game = Game.friendly.find(params[:game_id])
   @game_category = Game.friendly.find(@game.id).game_categories.new(game_category_params)

    if current_user.mod_of_game? params[:game_id] && @game_category.save

    Game.find(@game.id).game_categories.find(game_category.id).update(submitted_by: current_user.id)
    Game.find(@game.id).game_categories.find(game_category.id).update(approved_by: current_user.id)

      flash[:info] = "Game category added succesfully!"
      redirect_to @game
    else
      render 'new'
    end

end
```

These 2 lines are supposed to add the user id to the submitted_by and approved_by columns but they don't. I don't get any error messages, they simply just don't add anything to those columns

```
Game.find(@game.id).game_categories.find(game_category.id).update(submitted_by: current_user.id)
Game.find(@game.id).game_categories.find(game_category.id).update(approved_by: current_user.id)
```

If I replace the lines with coding that works in the console to see if its a variable or something thats not right it still doesn't work

```
Game.find(12).game_categories.find(55).update(submitted_by: 1)
Game.find(12).game_categories.find(55).update(approved_by: 1)
```

I'm building an app to learn rails and I guess this is something I just don't know.

Can anyone enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:**

Ok it is now giving me an error - Couldn't find GameCategory without an ID

So the @game_category.id isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

It is a small typo in your query you missed `@`.

`Game.find(@game.id).game_categories.find(@game_category.id).update(submitted_by: current_user.id)`

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work. i even tried `Game.find(12).game_categories.find(55).update(submitted_by: 1)` without variables and it still diddn't work

Answer (score 0):

After playing around tweaking it here and there it turns out to be this line

```
if current_user.mod_of_game? params[:game_id] && @game_category.save
```

when changed to this it works

```
if @game_category.save && current_user.mod_of_game? @game
```